# Using Numpy Array to Create Unique Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

Can you create a numpy array with all unique values in it?

```
myArray = numpy.random.random_integers(0,100,2500)
myArray.shape = (50,50)
```

So here I have a given random 50x50 numpy array, but I could have non-unique values.  Is there a way to ensure every value is unique?

Thank you

### Update:

I have created a basic function to generate a list and populate a unique integer.

```
        dist_x = math.sqrt(math.pow((extent.XMax - extent.XMin), 2))
        dist_y = math.sqrt(math.pow((extent.YMax - extent.YMin),2))
        col_x = int(dist_x / 100)
        col_y = int(dist_y / 100)
        if col_x % 100 > 0:
            col_x += 1
        if col_y % 100 > 0:
            col_y += 1
        print col_x, col_y, 249*169
        count = 1
        a = []

        for y in xrange(1, col_y + 1):
            row = []
            for x in xrange(1, col_x + 1):
                row.append(count)
                count += 1
            a.append(row)
            del row

        numpyArray = numpy.array(a)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be asking for 2500 unique random integers between 0 and 100. It should be pretty obvious why that's not going to happen...

Comment: I was asking if there was a built in method or a fast way to do this?

Comment: Do you need random numbers, or just unique? If just unique, maybe `np.random.permutation(np.arange(N))`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most convenient way to get a unique random sample from a set is probably  [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with `replace=False`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

# create a (5, 5) array containing unique integers drawn from [0, 100]
uarray = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 101), replace=False, size=(5, 5))

# check that each item occurs only once
print((np.bincount(uarray.ravel()) == 1).all())
# True
```

If `replace=False` the set you're sampling from must, of course, be at least as big as the number of samples you're trying to draw:

```
np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 101), replace=False, size=(50, 50))
# ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'
```

---

If all you're looking for is a random permutation of the integers between 1 and the number of elements in your array, you could also use [`np.random.permutation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) like this:

```
nrow, ncol = 5, 5
uarray = (np.random.permutation(nrow * ncol) + 1).reshape(nrow, ncol)
```

Comment: So if I know the number of columns/rows I should be able to do this? numpyArray = numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(1, (col_x*col_y)+1),
                                          replace=0,
                                          size=(col_x, col_y)).  This should lead to me getting the correct size with allowed unique values in each column/row location in the matrix.

Comment: Well, if you just want a random permutation of the elements in the (inclusive) range `[1, col_x * col_y]`, you might as well just use `(np.random.permutation(col_x * col_y) + 1).reshape(col_x, col_y)`, as I think @oja was hinting.

Answer (score 0):

Just use replace = False.

```
import numpy as np


def generate():
    global x
    powerball = np.random.randint(1,27)
    numbers = np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 70), replace=False, size=(1, 5))
    x = numbers, powerball
    return x

generate()
```